# Issues in numerical sorting of the files in a subfolder

Tags: python-3.x, file, sorting

I have written a function for returning the contents of folders which are like this

```
temp-vts1
.....
temp-vts10
```

Inside this, we have images, where I want to sort their contents numerically.
Contents--

```
temp-vts1-0.png
.....
temp-vts1-1000.png

Similarly, 
temp-vts2-0.png
temp-vts2-1.png.......
temp-vts2-999.png...
temp-vts2-1000.png...

Similarly for other 8 folders.
```

```
paths- it's sorting like this:
\user\...\temp-vts1-0.png
\user\...\temp-vts1-10.png....
```

```
but I WANT:- every image in numerical for each folder... How should I sort? 
\user\...\temp-vts1-0.png
\user\...\temp-vts1-1.png
\user\...\temp-vts1-2.png
....
\user\...\temp-vts1-1000.png
\user\...\temp-vts2-0.png
\user\...\temp-vts2-1.png
\user\...\temp-vts2-3.png..... rest folders like this.....
```

```
Code- where should I update?
        paths_frames = []
        for folder, subs, files in os.walk(path_data):        
            for filename in sorted(files):
                if filename[-3:].lower() == 'png':
                    paths_frames.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename)))
```

Comment: Please move your text out of your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = "temp-vts2-1.png"
txt.split("-")
# gives list that can be indexed ['temp', 'vst2', '1.png']
# also read  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html
# I think the mistake you are making is expecting sorted to sort by the number which are actually text.
```